# css, javascript: textarea текст разного цвета

Tags: javascript, html, css, color, textarea

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы часть текста в `textarea` поле было заданного цвета, отличного от основного цвета текста?

Знаю, что есть отдельные библиотеки, но для моих целей это избыточно. Вот и думаю, можно ли обойтись малой кровью.

Comment: что такое часть текста в вашем понимании

Comment: @qwabra, текстовой блок, текст от start_pos до end_pos. Другими словами, пользователь вводит текст в поле (textarea) и я хочу цветом показать некоторые части введённого текста, на которые стоит обратить внимание (выделить цветом). В сети есть библиотеки похожие на richedit, которые всё это позволят, но их функционал чрезмерно избыточен для моей задачи, вот и подумал, а нет ли возможности обойтись малыми силами.

Comment: можно отредактировать свой вопрос, кнопка править

Comment: парсить вводимый текст сами сможете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Стандартные элементы `textarea` и `input` не предоставляют возможностей форматирования отдельных подстрок их текстового содержимого, и не могут содержать вложенные строчные элементы (которым можно было бы задать CSS-стили).

Поэтому, данная задача обычно решается созданием имитации поля ввода:

1. Элементу,  предназначенному для в**ы**вода (обычно берется `div` или `span`), добавляют атрибут `contenteditable` - он включает возможность прямого редактирования текста содержимого;
2. CSS-стилями достигают внешнего сходства элемента со стандартным полем ввода - фон, бордер, прокрутка при переполнении, и т.д.. В контексте задачи, это самая легкая часть;
3. Пишут скрипт, который оборачивает части текстового содержимого в подэлементы (которые, в свою очередь, и оформляются средствами CSS). А также, реализуется поведение элемента, подобное поведению RichText-редактора. И вот это, уже весьма непросто.

Основная сложность - в получении и установке позиции каретки (текстового курсора)... актуальные веб-стандарты не предоставляют удобных средств для этого. Необходимо создавать велосипед, и довольно непростой (с нуля, подобный скрипт за 10 минут не написать).
Следовательно, если цель не в том чтобы создать свое - рациональнее будет использовать одну из множества готовых реализаций такого элемента ввода.

---

Простой пример подсветки (не "на лету"):

```js
const HL_RULES = [
  { cl: 'str',  re: /("[^"]+")/ }, 
  { cl: 'optr', re: /^(var|let|for|in|of|function|function*|const|do|while|break|continue|if|else|switch|case|default|try|catch|throw|delete|void|yield|yield*|return)$/ }, 
  { cl: 'cnst', re: /(\d+)/ }, 
  { cl: 'brcs', re: /({|})/ }
]; 

let txt = document.querySelector('.custom-textarea'),
    btn = document.getElementById('hl'); 
txt.addEventListener('focus', () => txt.innerHTML = txt.textContent); 
btn.addEventListener('click', () => simpleHighlighter(txt)); 
btn.click(); 

function simpleHighlighter(el) {
  if (el instanceof Event)
    el = this; 
  // если эту функцию назначать обработчиком input, то тут должен быть код сохранения позиции каретки... 
  let words = textToArray(el),
      html  = '', 
      rule; 
  words.forEach(word => {
    if (rule = getHlRuleFor(word))
      html += `<span class="${rule.cl}">${rule.m}</span>`; 
    else
      html += word; 
  });
  el.innerHTML = html; 
  // ..., а тут - код установки каретки обратно на сохраненную позицию
}

function textToArray(el) {
  const RE = /(^|\(+?|[^\w]+?)((?:"[^"]*")|(?:[{}\w]+))(\)+?[\S]+?)?/gmi;   // эта регулярка весьма далека от совершенства :)
  let result = [], 
      match, i; 
  while (match = RE.exec(el.textContent)) {
    for (i = 1; i < match.length; i++) {
      if (match[i])
        result.push(match[i]); 
    }
  }
  return result; 
}

function getHlRuleFor(word) {
  let rule, mr; 
  if (rule = HL_RULES.find(r => mr = word.match(r.re)))
    rule.m = mr[1]; 
  return rule; 
}
```

```css
* { font: 14px sans-serif; }
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.custom-textarea {
  min-width: 40ch; 
  min-height: 7em; height: 50%; 
  padding: 0.1em 0.3ch; margin: 0.5em 0; 
  overflow: auto; resize: both; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.custom-textarea,
.custom-textarea span {
  font-family: monospace; 
}

.str  { color: #e94; }
.optr { color: #47d; font-weight: 500; }
.cnst { color: #4a4; }
.brcs { color: #d44; }
```

```html
<pre class="custom-textarea" contenteditable="">function foo() {
  let a = "Последовательность чисел:";
  for (var i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    if (a === 13)
      alert("Попалось 'счастливое' число :)");
    a += " " + i;
  }
  return a; 
}
</pre>
<button id="hl">Подсветить синтаксис</button>
```

Comment: Фи, нет проверки на корректную вложенность!

Comment: @Other, в примере вообще отсутствует проверка на вложенность (хоть корректную, хоть не-). Потому что пример соответствует вопросу - он демонстрирует принцип подсветки текста, а не разбор кода. Для анализа кода применяется более сложная логика, чем один проход примитивной регуляркой.

Comment: Сарказм же! ::)

Comment: SO выработал у меня рефлекс такой реакции на комменты :))) Кстати, вообще я ожидал что кто-нибудь напишет другое: _"фи, оно одинарные кавычки не понимает"_. Ну, уж я бы точно так написал :D

Comment: Первое, что пришло на ум сказал.

Answer (score 0):

### в textarea работать не будет

```html
<textarea rows="7" contenteditable="true">
<h1>qwa</h1>
<p>qwa-qwa</p>
</textarea>
```

### зато можно так

введи @qwa

```js
// -----
var textarea = textarea || document.getElementById('textarea')
let timer = null // id таймера
let t = 1e3 // задержка в миллисекундах
textarea.addEventListener('keyup', foo)
// --
function highlightWords() {
  var original = textarea.textContent
  var replaced = original.replace(/@[a-zA-Z0-9]+/g,
        (username) => "<span class='exists'>" + username + "</span>")
  textarea.innerHTML = replaced
}

function foo(e) {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  if (e.srcElement.textContent) {
    timer = setTimeout(highlightWords, t);
  }
}
```

```css
div[contenteditable=true] {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}

.exists {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="textarea">
  <h1>qwa</h1>
  <p>qwa-<b>qwa</b></p>
  <center>center</center>
</div>
```

данный пример взят и отредактирован отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/21420554/4794368

Comment: Читаю и не могу понять на кой в первом примере `textarea` атрибут `contenteditable`? В чем соль? И в чем суть второго варианта?