# Как реализовать подсветку в <code>?

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

Как сделать такую подсветку, как у нас на `StackOverFlow`?

Comment: Если вопрос о том как написать самому - возможно, пример их этого ответа будет полезен: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/811950/288409

Comment: Упс, я не заметил что вопрос для самоответа.

Comment: Просто хотел поделиться — мне это не давно пригодилось , а у нас не аналога такого вопроса как на enSО. Ссылка полезная , спасибо!

Comment: Самоответы это всегда гуд, просто с моей стороны как-то некрасиво получилось (как будто противопоставляю пример ответу - но это конечно не так). Лучше удалить коммент, или оставить?

Comment: Не , комменты стоит оставить — они мне тоже пригодились. И другим не помешают.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_syntax_highlight.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[К примеру вот так:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647724/color-syntax-highlighting-within-an-html-code-tag)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/google/code-prettify@master/loader/run_prettify.js">       </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <pre class="prettyprint lang-py">
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
                
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```